# Ripley's K function and toroidal shift with Splancs

Tags: r

R's Splancs library implements bivariate K function with confidence envelope with the function `Kenv.tor`. The function takes `poly` as an argument, and doesn't seem to restrict it to be rectangular. In the detail section of the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splancs/splancs.pdf), it says

> The second point data set is randomly shifted using rotr.shift in the
> rectangle defined by poly.

But the study area is not necessarily rectangular.

If we use the toroidal shift with the bounds as the rectangle, wouldn't some of the shifted points fall outside the polygon?

If so, wouldn't this affect the K function simulation results?

If in fact the points are actually sure to fall within the polygon after the random shifts, how is it done and how can it be achieved efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. The code takes the bounding box of your polygon window and uses that. Yup points will get shifted out of the window. Quite how that breaks things I'm not sure, but `splancs` never was much for checking valid values. A window was a general polygon and there was no checking of rectangles in functions where rectangles were the sensible option.

Sure if I could go back 30 years I'd rewrite most of `splancs` to have better error and sanity checking, but I'd probably do a lot of other things first.

`spatstat` does most things `splancs` does, and often better, and I heartily recommend it for point pattern analysis. I suspect `splancs` may retire before I do.